# How to replace elements in array with elements of another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, concatenation, array-replace

I want to replace elements in some array from 0 element, with elements of another array with variable length. Like:

```
var arr = new Array(10), anotherArr = [1, 2, 3], result;
result = anotherArr.concat(arr);
result.splice(10, anotherArr.length);
```

Is there some better way?

Comment: @NagaJolokia, [1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined ...]

Comment: With length === 10, right?

Comment: And is arr always empty, or can it sometimes have contents?

Comment: always empty in my case

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the `splice` method to replace part of an array with items from another array, but you have to call it in a special way as it expects the items as parameters, not the array.

The `splice` method expects parameters like `(0, anotherArr.Length, 1, 2, 3)`, so you need to create an array with the parameters and use the `apply` method to call the `splice` method with the parameters:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));
```

Example:

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var anotherArr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));

console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bB7Ey/

Comment: If the first array is longer than the replacement the above solution won't remove the extra elements on the end. This slight modification will:
Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [0, arr.length].concat(anotherArr));

Comment: @perilandmishap: Yes, that was the point. If you want to replace the array you can just replace the entire object: `arr = anotherArr;`.

Comment: In Flux/Redux style state managers frequently you're working with a const and not permitted to change the reference to your object, so just doing reassignment isn't an option. It's a silly problem to have, but the state of javascript is a little silly at the moment.

Comment: How about `arr.splice(0, anotherArr.length, ...anotherArray);` ?

Comment: @AdamCox: Yes, that would work now. The spread operator wasn't available in most browsers until 2015.

Answer (score 63):

In ES6 with a single operation, you can do this to replace the first `b.length` elements of `a` with elements of `b`:

```
let a = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
let b = [10, 20, 30]

a.splice(0, b.length, ...b)

console.log(a) // -> [10, 20, 30, 4, 5]
```

It could be also useful to **replace the entire content of an array**, using `a.length` (or `Infinity`) in the splice length:

```
let a = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
let b = [10, 20, 30]

a.splice(0, a.length, ...b)
// or
// a.splice(0, Infinity, ...b)

console.log(a) // -> [10, 20, 30], which is the content of b
```

The `a` array's content will be entirely replaced by `b` content.

Note 1: in my opinion the array mutation should only be used in performance-critical applications, such as high FPS animations, to avoid creating new arrays. Normally I would create a new array maintaining immutability.

Note 2: if `b` is a very large array, this method is discouraged, because `...b` is being *spread* in the arguments of `splice`, and there's a limit on the number of parameters a JS function can accept. In that case I encourage to use another method (or create a new array, if possible!).

Comment: Nice solution! This is better than the one involving `length` because I can also map over the same array. E.g. `let a = [5, 6, 7, 8]; a.splice(0, a.length, ...a.map(x => x * x));` And it doesn't require reassignment to `a` either.

Comment: Just use `a.splice(0, Infinity, ...b)`. The second arguments is irrelevant as long as it's larger than the number of elements to be removed.

Comment: Nice, but the initial question was how to replace part of the first array. It should be `a.splice(0, b.length, ...b)` - with length of b measured instead. It will work correctly with any lengths of both arrays

Comment: This is *v* slow for large arrays and can end up in `Maximum recursion depth exceeced`

Comment: @javadba that's right, for very large arrays I think you should create a new array. I believe the cycling time does overcome the creation time. (anyway, the `Maximum recursion` error is quite cryptic... There's no recursion in that code, and I think there is never any recursion in browser implementations)

Comment: @javadba I added a Note 2 to give this warning! thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In ES6, TypeScript, Babel or similar you can just do:

```js
arr1.length = 0; // Clear your array
arr1.push(...arr2); // Push the second array using the spread opperator
```

Simple.

Comment: Simlpe, but what if its a associative array?

Comment: @TimBogdanov JS does not have associate arrays, you may be thinking of a an `Object` used as an `Array` (and an `Array` is an `Object` and can double in this role, but it's unorthodox and unadvised), or the newer `Map` object.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for a way to replace the entire contents of one array with entire contents of another array while preserving the original array:

```
Array.prototype.replaceContents = function (array2) {
    //make a clone of the 2nd array to avoid any referential weirdness
    var newContent = array2.slice(0);
    //empty the array
    this.length = 0;
    //push in the 2nd array
    this.push.apply(this, newContent);
};
```

The prototype function takes an array as a parameter which will serve as the new array content, clones it to avoid any weird referential stuff, empties the original array, and then pushes in the passed in array as the content.  This preserves the original array and any references.

Now you can simply do this:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
arr1.replaceContents(arr2);
```

I know this is not strictly what the initial question was asking, but this question comes up first when you search in google, and I figured someone else may find this helpful as it was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), can add new elements while removing old ones:

```
var arr = new Array(10), anotherArr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.splice.apply(arr, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr))
```

If you don't want to modify the `arr` array, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) that returns a shallow copy of the array:

```
var arr = new Array(10), anotherArr = [1, 2, 3], result = arr.slice(0);

result.splice.apply(result, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));
```

Alternatively, you can use `slice` to cut off the first elements and adding the `anotherArr` on `top`:

```
result = anotherArr.concat(arr.slice(anotherArr.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a "better" way, but at least it allows you to choose the starting index (whereas your solution only works starting at index 0). [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/9weUf/)

```
// Clone the original array
var result = arr.slice(0);
// If original array is no longer needed, you can do with:
// var result = arr;

// Remove (anotherArr.length) elements starting from index 0
// and insert the elements from anotherArr into it
Array.prototype.splice.apply(result, [0, anotherArr.length].concat(anotherArr));
```

(Damnit, so many ninjas. :-P)

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the length of the array in this case. For more complex cases see @Guffa's answer.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.length = 10;
a; // [1, 2, 3, undefined x 7]
```