# how to unpack the values of one array into the specific index of another array?

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following code in order to create a simple machine language array of commands.

```
// to ensure consistency, initialize an array of values.
var cmd = _.chunk(_.range(0, 300, 0), 30);

_.each(doses, function (dose, index) {
  // these are "headers" to the machine language instructions.
  cmd[index][0] = 1;
  cmd[index][1] = dose.number;

  // this generates the 28 commands to be executed.
  // every four blocks together represents a single command
  var commands = _.flatten(_.map(_.chunk(_.range(0, 28, 0), 4), function (day) {
    _.each(dose.wellIndexes, function (well) {
      day[well] = dose.count.value;
    });
    return day;
  }));
});
```

(Still WIP code).
With this `commands` array, I want to unpack it's values into `cmd[index][2]`, such that it will fill the remainder of the array. Is this possible?

Looking at the docs, I have found [merging two arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), but this does not replace the values after an index, only appends to the array.

How do you unpack array values into another array in javascript?

Comment: Sounds like `Array.slice` is what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [a simple mix of splice, concat and apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511398/1439597) should do the trick:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(cmd[index], [2, commands.length].concat(commands));
```

That is, if you need to keep some data at the end of your `cmd[index]` array. (in other word, your `commands` array is shorter than the rest of `cmd[index]` starting from index 2) If that is not a concern, then just splice the array and concatenate your commands to it.

Comment: nice, I thought an apply was necessary but couldn't quite figure out where