# How to replace array elements in place

Tags: javascript

I want to attach a new method to the Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function(){
  return this.filter((val, index) => {
    return this.indexOf(val) === index;
  });
};

var a = [1, 1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.uniq()); // output： [1,2,3]
console.log(a); // output: [1,1,2,3]
```

The method removes duplicates from an array. The problem I have is that whenever `uniq` is called, a new array is returned. I want to do something like this:

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function(){
  this = this.filter((val, index) => {  // "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    return this.indexOf(val) === index;
  });
};
```

so that:

```
var a = [1, 1, 2, 3];
a.uniq();
console.log(a); // output: [1,2,3]
```

What should I do?

Comment: why not just do `a = a.uniq()`?

Comment: @Schleis sure that works, but I am just curious how to do it inside prototype

Comment: [How to replace elements in array with elements of another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511273/how-to-replace-elements-in-array-with-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the array using `for` loop and use `splice` if the index are not same.

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function () {
    // Reverse iterate
    for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // If duplicate
        if (this.indexOf(this[i]) !== i) {
            // Remove from array
            this.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    // Return updated array
    return this;
};

var a = [1, 1, 2, 3];
a.uniq();
console.log(a); // output: [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thx! I thought about splice but the index changes as I remove elements from the array. Reverse iterate is very smart :)  The `return this` line is not needed right?

Comment: Tushar, shouldn't the indexes inside the for loop be `i-1` because `i = this.length` makes `this[i]` out of the loop.