# Replace elements of an array with elements of another array based on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays,

```
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]
```

I want to replace the contents of **array1** with elements of **array2** when **array1** element and **array2** `id` element's value matches.
Result should be something like this:

```
array1 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}]
```

I know I can get the result in a separate array, but I want to replace the contents of array1 without having to create a new array.

I tried this:

```
array1.splice(0, Infinity, ...array2)
```

based on an answer given to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762985/7541082)

This results in:

```
array1 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]
```

I tried different ways to add a condition to this statement but failed. Is there a way to add a condition to the splice method above? Or if there is a better way of achieving it, do suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [keyed collection - Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get items by key.

```js
const array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

const array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]

const array2Map = new Map(array2.map(o=> [o.id, o]));

const result = array1.map(o => ({
  ...array2Map.get(o)
}));
console.log(result);
```

In addition, you can use `filter` and `some` methods to achieve desired result:

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]       

array1 = array2.filter(f=> array1.some(s=> s == f.id));

console.log(array1);
```

Another way, however more verbose and not optimal:

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]       

array1 = array1.map(a => {
    let obj = array2.find(a2=> a2.id == a);
    if (obj) return obj;
    return a;
})

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also search for the array2 ids in array1 then replace array1's indices with the matching array2 indices.

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]

array2.forEach(function(e){
    if(array1.indexOf(e["id"]) != -1) {
        array1[array1.indexOf(e["id"])] = e
    }
})

console.log(array1)
```

EDIT: I tried a different approach by mapping each values in array1 with comparing values of array2 ids in filter, I don't think if it's a cleaner solution but I tried:

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]

array1 = array1.map(num => {
  return array2.filter(dict => {
    if(dict["id"] == num) {return dict}
  })[0]
})

console.log(array1)
```

If you can use lodash, it is pretty short:

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]

array1 = _.map(array1, function(o){return _.find(array2, {id: o})})

console.log(array1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There must be a shorter way of achieving this without having to loop through the array ?

Comment: I updated the answer with two more methods in order that any of them complies with you. The answer sent by @StepUp below looks like the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Array.filter` will do the job?

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
array1 = [
  {"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, 
  {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, 
  {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, 
  {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}
].filter(v => array1.includes(v.id));

// using Array.indexOf (IE >= 9, nodejs all versions), 
let array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
array2 = [
  {"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, 
  {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, 
  {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, 
  {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}
].filter(v => array2.indexOf(v.id) > -1);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: this works but `includes` isn't supported by internet explorer and and also not supported for node.js versions below 6.0.0 according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: If browser (or even nodejs) compatibility is really an issue, you can use the polyfill (https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill)

Comment: @hushie you could have mentioned the compatibility requirement in the question

Comment: @Kooilnc I should have, I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}]       

array1 = array2.filter(f=> array1.find(s=> s == f.id));

console.log(array1);

/**outPut :[
  {
"name": "a",
"id": "1"
  },
  {
"name": "b",
"id": "2"
  },
  {
"name": "c",
"id": "3"
  }
]**/
```